# How to create a dictionary of dates as keys with value pair as list of three temperatures in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, sqlite, dictionary

The function extracts the max, min and avg temperatures for all days in the list.  I want to combine the data into a dictionary; i.e. the returned temperatures and values and the dates as keys. Can't seem to get this to work. I may be going about this in the wrong way. End aim is to create a chart with date  and the three temperatures for each day.  I was anticipating something like: my_dict: {date,[list of 3 temps], date2,[list of 3 temps2]...}

```
lstdates=['09-27','09-28','09-29','09-30','10-1']
def daily_normals(date):
    """Daily Normals.

    Args:
        date (str): A date string in the format '%m-%d'

    Returns:
        A list of tuples containing the daily normals, tmin, tavg, and tmax

    """

    sel = [func.min(meas.tobs), func.avg(meas.tobs), func.max(meas.tobs)]
    return session.query(*sel).filter(func.strftime("%m-%d", meas.date) == date).all()

lstdaynorm=[]
my_dict ={}
for i in lstdates:    
    print(i)
    dn=daily_normals(l)
    lstdaynorm.append(dn)
    my_dict.append(i,dn)
```

Comment: What is an example return value of `daily_normals`?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, a `dict` object has no method called `append`, so `my_dict.append(i,dn)` is invalid syntax. Also, your iterator variable is `i`, but you called `daily_normals` on `l`. You should convert the `tuple` `dn` to a `list` and directly insert that `list` into the `dict` to achieve what you want:

```
lstdaynorm=[]
my_dict = {}
for i in lstdates:
    dn=daily_normals(i)
    lstdaynorm.append(dn)
    my_dict[i] = list(dn[0][1:]) # extract elements of tuple excluding date from list and convert it to list

my_dict = dict(my_dict)
```

To put this in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index', columns=['tmin', 'tavg', 'tmax'])
```

Comment: Much appreciate the help. Very new to python.
when I try this i get an error:
**name 'collection' is not defined**

Comment: @JamesTurner I updated my answer removing that part, because I misunderstood your requirement at first. Also, can you include an example return value of `daily_normals` so I know what data I'm dealing with? I'm not understanding at the moment why it returns a list of tuples and what each tuple represents

Comment: Not your fault. I'm operating on very limited python knowledge. the function was provided by class instructors. I did incorporate meas.date into the list, then tried to convert that to a DF, but I get a DF with one column made of the list, i need the date as index and temps inseparate columns.

Comment: @JamesTurner can you print out `dn` after this line `dn=daily_normals(l)` and include the output here? Once I know what this looks like I can guide you on how to add it to your `dict`

Comment: print(dn)

[('2014-09-26', 66.0, 75.64, 85.0)]

[('2010-09-27', 68.0, 75.64, 83.0)]
[('2013-09-28', 67.0, 76.13461538461539, 84.0)]
[('2014-09-29', 68.0, 75.97872340425532, 83.0)]

Comment: @JamesTurner I updated my answer, let me know if it works for you

Comment: yes that worked. so did the the previous code. It creates a dictionary with dates as keys, and list of temps.  I feel silly, but this leaves me with another problem which further emphasizes by inexperience.

how can I extract the temps from the list so that I can put the dictionary into a data frame 

date    tmin   tavg  tmax  as dataframe columns

Comment: @JamesTurner btw, I also changed this line `my_dict[i] = list(dn[0])` to this `my_dict[i] = list(dn[0][1:])` because I forgot to exclude the date from the tuple

Comment: That did it!  THANK YOU!